# Adding tasks to Microsoft To Do using voice only - goes to Keep instead

Tags: google-assistant, voice-command, android-auto, to-do-list

I recently moved from Google Tasks to Microsoft ToDo and it's very good, which should not be a surprise considering it's Wunderlist [underneath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wunderlist).

Using Android Auto in the car, I want to be able to add to my *Microsoft To Do* Tasks list using voice only. [Microsoft Support says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/using-ok-google-with-microsoft-to-do-94d3c3f0-9f4c-4e8d-a57d-439cd69e1f61) to use voice commands with *Microsoft To Do* on Android, tap the microphone icon in the Google search bar, say "Ok Google, add a note...", and select *Microsoft To Do* as your default app.

That does not work for me though when I just say "Ok Google, add a note...", without taping first, a note gets added to Google Keep. I can't see anywhere to change the default so it's added to the *Tasks* list in *Microsoft To Do*.

Has anyone been able to get it working?

Comment: You may need to say "Ok Google, create a note on Microsoft ToDo", based on: https://developer.android.com/reference/app-actions/built-in-intents/productivity/create-digital-document#example-queries

Comment: As mentioned by Morrison Chang, based on my experiment with WhatsApp with the help of [Google Assistant Help](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/9984245), mentioning the app name directly might affect the result.

Comment: I tried that but it still went to Keep:[see voice commands and keep](https://postimg.cc/5X685Jfh)

Answer (score 1):

I found an old [techcommunity post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-to-do-insiders-for/current-microsoft-to-do-integration-with-google-assistant/m-p/3861326/highlight/true#M270) that gave me a close solution for Samsung only which works for me though it would be nice to have a nonproprietary solution and not to need an intermediary app.

1. **Requires a Samsung phone**. Enable *Bixby*, Samsung's virtual assistant, by searching for the *Bixby* app and clicking enable. In the *Settings* -> *Language and voice style*, you can choose one of 2 voices.
2. Enable the hidden reminder app on your Samsung phone by opening the Samsung calendar, selecting the menu, and tapping reminder, You will be taken to the reminder app and an app shortcut will be added to your app screen.
3. Open the Samsung reminder app -> *Settings* & tap *Sync with Microsoft To Do*, sign in with your Microsoft account, and accept the permission request.
4. You now see the synced *Tasks* under *Microsoft To Do*
5. You can now say "Hey Bixby add a reminder to walk the dog"
6. Go into the reminder and see "Walk the dog" as a new Task. It will have a red dot after it, which disappears when it has synced. The To Do then shows in your To Do task list.

- Initially when I did the last step earlier the note appeared in *To Do* under a new list called Reminder. I am unsure how this changed to go into Tasks but it's working now.